# This question should be reopened. It is not asking about a specific choice (Done)

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[HR employee sent me code test but not know open .c file. Serious problems?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/122033/should-not-work-in-software-company-have-hr-employee-send-me-code-test-but-not-k)

This question should be reopened. It isn't asking about a specific choice.

Comment: Way ahead of you :) I cleaned the post up a bit as there was some slight language barrier clunkiness.